# Is there any way to use some kind of environment variable in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

how to create and use environment variables in vue js? only raw vue without webpack or anything else, im using vue with laravel

to differentiate the variables we need to be different in multiple environment

thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a way without webpack, your best match would be vue.config https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Global-Config

Answer (score 0):

If you can use localStorage/Cookie to save a value in the browser, use the corresponding environment based on the value

example：

```
 var config={}
 if(localStorage.environment=="test")
   config={env:'test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage or variables to save the env file. But I would recommend using webpack.

Sometimes it is practical to have different config values according to the environment that the application is running in.

As an example:

```
// config/prod.env.js
module.exports = {
NODE_ENV: '"production"',
DEBUG_MODE: false,
API_KEY: '"..."' // this is shared between all environments
}

// config/dev.env.js
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
NODE_ENV: '"development"',
DEBUG_MODE: true // this overrides the DEBUG_MODE value of prod.env
})

// config/test.env.js
module.exports = merge(devEnv, {
NODE_ENV: '"testing"'
})
```

For more detail you can access this [Link](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/env.html)